# Add custom HTML element to form iteration object in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I am iterating a form object in my view file to create form elements. Now I want to add few tool tips for some specific form elements and password strength meter to password field. Is there anything like partial form elements or kindda thing to add my custom HTML elements to the form object?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if you want to add custom HTML you'll have to render out the elements manually. You could do something like this tho:

```
foreach (array('name', 'description', ...) as $name) {
    echo $this->formRow($form->get($name));
}

// manually render your special tooltip and element in here

foreach (array('more', 'elements', ...) as $name) {
    echo $this->formRow($form->get($name));
}
```

The alternate approach would be to simply render out the form and add the tooltip via JS later. What kind of "custom HTML" do you want to "add to the element"?

Comment: I am creating the user adding form. So, there are two tool tips just next to the user name field and password field, and password strength checker below the password filed. As am dynamically adding fields to the form, wonder how to add above custom html tags in related places.

Comment: Since that is a small form i simply suggest to read the [Zend\Form Rendering Documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#rendering) and manually render the form. Would give you the least troubles ;)

Comment: I kept it for the last option. Anyway, lets do it in  that way. Thank you very much